# How to debug line by line in REACT using VS code editor?

Tags: reactjs, debugging, visual-studio-code

I am learning REACT and would like to know how to setup line by line debugger for my code for debugging. I have been doing backend development using ASP.net and recently started learning REACT with a project started by another developer. Unfortunately, I am having issues setting up line by line debugging capability in VS code for REACT. I followed the tutorial [here](https://www.bing.com/videos/search?q=how%20to%20debug%20line%20by%20line%20react%20code%20in%20vs%20code&docid=608036832657738797&mid=A8559B56F2F8EA31F20CA8559B56F2F8EA31F20C&view=detail&FORM=VIRE) but it does not stop at breakpoints I setup.

Following is the code where I set up breakpoints (This is part of apps.ts) - Breakpoints are the circles to the left.
[image]

This is my Launch.json file :

[image]

Could you please please help me to get this set up right? I need line by line debugging to fully understand the flow of REACT since this is new to me.

What else is missing here to enable line by line debugging?

Thanks,
PG

Comment: The code you added is not React!

Comment: Yes, it's NodeJS backend :)

Answer (score 2):

This is my working Launch script. This enabled debugging my code line by line with breakpoints. Also, this is with Edge chromium-browser. (Latest VS code editor)

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Launch localhost in Microsoft Edge",
            "type": "edge",
            "request": "launch",
            "url": "http://localhost:3000/api",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/ABC-MVP/backend/src",
            "sourceMapPathOverrides": {
                "webpack:///*": "*",
                "webpack:///./*": "${webRoot}/*",
                "webpack:///src/*": "${webRoot}/*",
                "webpack:///./~/*": "${webRoot}/node_modules/*"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "Launch index.html in Microsoft Edge",
            "type": "edge",
            "request": "launch",
            "port": 3000,
            "file": "${workspaceFolder}/index.html"
        },
        {
            "type": "node",
            "name": "Debug CRA Tests",
            "request": "launch",
            "args": [
              "app.ts",
              "--runInBand",
              "--no-cache",
              "--env=jsdom"
            ],
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "console": "internalConsole",
            //"console": "integratedTerminal",
            "internalConsoleOptions": "openOnSessionStart",
            "disableOptimisticBPs": true,
            "runtimeExecutable":
              "${workspaceFolder}/ABC-MVP/backend/node_modules/.bin/react-scripts",
              //"${workspaceFolder}/ABC-MVP/backend/src/models",
              "protocol": "inspector"
          }
    ]
}
```

Comment: I had to replace `edge` with `msedge`

Answer (score 1):

I think your Launch.json is OKay. The only thing that differs from ASP.Net is that, your first have to start your app with npm start or yarn start and then hit Debugger to launch the debugger. circle's show that your App is not currently running that's why they won't be hit.
And Yes the most IMP thing is, **your current code is not React Front-end.** It's NodeJS Backend, so follow [this guide](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/nodejs-debugging) to debug that code.

Comment: I managed to get it working and the launch script is in my answere.